# Display log lines on screen using parallel GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, spyder

I'm looking for elegant way to display log lines on screen while the script is running.

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk


class WaitGuiPrallel(Thread):
    def __init__(self, TXT='Wait!', ttl='Logs'):
        self.txt = TXT
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ttl = ttl
        self.start()  # This is starting the self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.root.title(self.ttl)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text=self.txt, font=("Helvetica", 20))
        self.label.pack()
        self.Location()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def Exit(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def Location(self):
        w = 500  # width for the Tk root
        h = 150  # height for the Tk root
        ws = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()  # width of the screen
        self.root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, ws - w - 20, 10))

    def Update(self, newText):
        self.txt1 = newText
        self.label.destroy()
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text=self.txt1,
                              font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.label.pack()
        self.root.update()

Wait = WaitGuiPrallel(TXT='Wait! Do not touch mouse or keyboard')
sleep(2)
for t in range(5):
    sleep(1)
    Wait.Update(newText='Log line %s' % t)
Wait.Update(newText='Done!')
sleep(1)
Wait.Exit()
```

The current script got few issues:

1. it is not elegant - there must be a better way
2. it has problems when updated from different Threads
3. Sometime running it twice from Spyder+IPython is not possible (IPython freeze)

Comment: You mean you want 2 windows open at once? Forget about threads, just use `tk.Toplevel` to make the second window.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter doesn't really play well with threads. Using a StringVar is a little more thread friendly than other methods (in my experience). Here's how to do that plus a couple other fixes:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk

class WaitGuiPrallel(Thread):
    def __init__(self, TXT='Wait!', ttl='Logs'):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.txt = TXT
        self.ttl = ttl # what's this for?
        self.daemon = True # this thread will terminate when the main thread terminates
        self.start()  # This is starting the self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.root.title(self.ttl)
        self.txt = tk.StringVar(value=self.txt)
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.txt, font=("Helvetica", 20))
        self.label.pack()
        self.Location()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def Location(self):
        w = 500  # width for the Tk root
        h = 150  # height for the Tk root
        ws = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()  # width of the screen
        self.root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, ws - w - 20, 10))

Wait = WaitGuiPrallel(TXT='Wait! Do not touch mouse or keyboard')
sleep(2)
for t in range(5):
    sleep(1)
    Wait.txt.set('Log line %s' % t)
Wait.txt.set('Done!')
sleep(1)
```

If you have multiple threads calling this then I would consider using a Queue and a third thread to monitor the queue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your script do not work (on my computer). You can't make 'Wait.txt.set(...)' and if changing it to 'Wait.txt = 'Log line %s' % t' it do not updated, and do not close the widget in the end.

Comment: I tested it and it works for me. Does it give you an error message? If  you want to change the syntax to work with `Wait.txt = 'Log line %s' % t'` you will need to make a property setter.

Comment: When using Spyder+IPython it is runing in the first time, but on 2nd run it gives an error: RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop